# Order of precedence if more than one style rule applies to an element

Tags: html, css

In HTML, When more than one style rule applies to an element, what is the order of precedence?

```
Rules that apply to an element identified by an id
Rules that apply to all elements of a particular class
Rules that apply to one or more specified tags
```

I think is id>class>tags, am I right?

Comment: @Andy - That would make 10 classes worth an id. one id is worth more than any number of classes in the specificity rules.

Comment: @Andy that is only a helper to remind you the 'worthiness', not exact values.

Comment: @Alohci it was actually proven that `1×id` = `255×class`, i.e. `256×class` trumps one `id` – http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lzjqh

Comment: @AdamKiss - Thanks, that's really interesting. That seems to be a violation of the intent of the CSS spec, though not the letter of the spec which just says that a large number base should be used. Actually it seems that browsers take that number base to be 256, 256xclass = 1xid, and so if there are exactly 256 classes and 1 id, the latter rule wins.

Comment: yeah, I forgot to mention that :D

Comment: @Alohci: Correct; that is an implementation limitation, and is not 100% conformant to the intent of the spec. In an ideal implementation, no overflow is supposed to occur; a single ID selector should always outweigh any number of class selectors. A base of 256 was most likely chosen to balance performance with practicality (i.e. realistically no one would craft a selector that requires 256 classes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Explanation

There are multiple things in play (as usual…), but the important order for you is this:

- styles with highest specificity are used
- if more have the same specificty, the latest is used

Order of selectors [and/or usage of css, for completness] (and what they add to specificity value is):

- tag
- class
- id
- inline styles (via `style=""`)
- `!important`
- tag + `!important`
- class + `!important`
- id + `!important`
- inline styles + `!important`

There were tests which showed that `256` classes on one element/selector have higher specificity then id. But in real life, you'll mostly (if you ever do CSS 'right') deal with number of classes + position in css file (you shouldn't style with #id, as it gives you no advantage over classes, and tags are mostly used only for generic styles)

Read more about specificity here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

## Example

HTML:

```
<div id="johnny" class="walker whisky"> -- </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* example one */
div { border-color: red; } // border is red
.whisky { border-color: brown; } // now it's brown
#johnny { border-color: black; } // now it's black
div#johnny { border-color: red; } // it's red again
.walker { border-color: green !important; } // it's green

/* example two */ 
.whisky {border-color: brown; }
.whisky.walker {border-color: green; }
/* green */

/* example two */ 
.whisky.walker {border-color: brown; }
.whisky {border-color: green !important; }
/* green */
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think you understand what a selector is. Oh and those 256-class tests are based on an implementation limitation and are not reliable. See my reply to Alohci above.

Comment: @BoltClock 1.) I don't see any incorrect usage of word selector anywhere. 2.) You are working with implementation, not specification; And the 256 classes was just a note, as you are (usually) not anywhere close.

Comment: Hm, I may have found it, if you referred to the list of 'selectors' (when in fact one was css declaration, and the other one was html attribute). I mention it only because IRL it contributes a lot to CSS specifity [issues]

Answer (score 3):

> I think is id>class>tags, am I right?

Yes, you are.

This is called specificity; refer to [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) and [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) for details.

Comment: You should include this link too, total specificity explanation, very handy to refer http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Anything that uses "points" to measure specificity I will avoid recommending because that system is flawed. Just count how many IDs, classes, tags, etc and compare them individually.

Comment: I guess specificity also includes order of id's classes and tags defined in the stylesheet..

Comment: No, specificity doesn't include the order.

Comment: @Andy ya exactly that's what I meant, the latter 1 will over ride

Comment: @Mr.Alien - Latter one wins is part of the cascade rules, not part of the specificity rules.

Comment: @Andy: What Alohci said. If two selectors have the same specificity, then it's no longer a matter of specificity but a different issue since you can't compare two selectors if they're the same.

Answer (score 0):

For playing around with style formatting rules, I'd advise using e.g.: Chrome, as it's Web Developer Plugin gives you insight on how rules are actually applied to a specific node...